# How to identify and extract boolean, integer etc data from json

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json

In UI, I create a object and set one of the property as boolean :

```
function UserObject(componentId, componentName, checkedOut) {
    this.componentId = componentId;
    this.componentName = componentName;
    this.checkedOut = checkedOut; //this is boolean variable
}
```

But from backend, while I set boolean values in my object, json converts it into string.

```
private UserObject createUserObject(EntityDTO entity) {
    UserObject userObject = new UserObject();
    userObject.setComponentId(entity.getEntityId());
    userObject.setComponentName(entity.getEntityName());
    userObject.setCheckedOut(entity.getCheckedOut());
    return userObject;
}
```

Now, here is the problem, I match some conditions twice (1) while creating (2) later while getting data from backend. Whenever I match the conditions for "checkedOut" object, it fails for the case when object comes from backend:

```
if(cell.value.checkedOut === true){
    //some code
}else{
    //some more code
}
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(cell.value.checkedOut === "true"){
    //some code
}else{
    //some more code
}
```

As it is a string in json now use double quotes for comparision

Comment: But then it wont work in case of creation, see I match condition twice :
(1) While creating
(2) Later while getting data from backend.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert string "true or false" to boolean type, use `eval()`:

```js
if(eval(cell.value.checkedOut) === true) {
    //some code
} else {
    //some more code
}
```